# Electron: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Tags: node.js, electron, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to run Google Text-To-Speech in electron using the [NodeJs Text To Speech Client Libary](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-text-to-speech)

I am able to use `require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');` within the `main.js` of my project (where the browser window is created)` but cannot run it within a script from within the page.

The error I get is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
    at Object.basename (path.js:671:5)
    at GrpcClient.loadProto (path\to\project\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:117:29)
    at new TextToSpeechClient (path\to\project\node_modules\@google-cloud\text-to-speech\build\src\v1\text_to_speech_client.js:106:32)
    at file://path/to/project/scripts/speech/ttscli.js:7:16
```

from this [code](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) located in `scripts/speech/ttscli.js`

`nodeIntegration` is set to true, and `scripts/speech/ttscli.js` is used like so:

```
<script src="./scripts/speech/ttscli.js"></script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>       at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
>       at Object.basename (path.js:671:5)

That's an easy one: you aren't passing in a valid path (of type string).

```
<script src="./scripts/speech/ttscli.js"></script>
```

You don't mention your project structure – where is your `renderer` context relative to the path above? Do a `console.log(__dirname)`in your page script to see the page path and compare it to the path above.

Comment: According to the docs of the client, I don't need to parse any argument or options?

Comment: I ran `console.log(__dirname);` within `ttscli.js` and it returned `C:\Users\sam02\WebstormProjects\face` (my project root)

Comment: It's hard to tell your  project structure from what you have posted so far. It is clearly just a path issue. Was this in the actual error or did you change it to hide personal info: `path\to\project\`

Comment: `path\to\project` is `C:\Users\sam02\WebstormProjects\face` (to hide personal info). Ideally I would like to use the module without modifying it. Otherwise I'm unsure how to fix said path issue.